# Spatial join between polygon with multipolygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip, attribute-joins, mmqgis

I have two layers in QGIS - `wgs84` representing the study area and `nycIncome` which I would like to clip based on where polygons intersect those of `wgs84`

Both layers are in the same CRS and have almost identical geometry, but they are not the same.  Whenever I try to run a spatial join using FIRST in the `MMQGIS` plugin, however, QGIS crashes.

Is there a reason why this is happening and what would be the correct way to take the intersection between a polygon and multipolygon?

[image]

[image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Intersection Tool coming with QGIS (Vector > Geoprocessing Tools). A Spatial Join only works on the attributes of the polygons, it doesn't change geometry.